# PHP function (shortcut) use

Tags: php, function

I have set in myFile.php this function:

```
    function monthLanguage()
{ 
    if ($this->lang=='italian')//this statement is requared many times within the file!
    {
        $dayName[]="Dom";
        $dayName[]="Lun";
        $dayName[]="Mar";
        $dayName[]="Mer";
        $dayName[]="Gio";
        $dayName[]="Ven";
        $dayName[]="Sab";
    }else
    {       
        $dayName[]="Sun";
        $dayName[]="Mon";
        $dayName[]="Tue";
        $dayName[]="Wed";
        $dayName[]="Thu";
        $dayName[]="Fri";
        $dayName[]="Sat";       
    }
}
```

I was thinking to wrap this if statement into a function to call it where is needed as a kind of short code.

I call it like this:

```
monthLanguage();
```

but I get error message: **Call to undefined function**

Any help on how to reach my short code intent?

Comment: Since you're using `$this` in your code I'm going to assume it's in a class. If you're calling it from inside your class, use `$this->monthLanguage();` else `$classInstantiator->monthLanguage();`.

Comment: Can you add the code calling it? is monthLanguage inside a class, as it seems you are using $this

Comment: And make sure you are including that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including the `monthLanguage` function the file you are using it in?  Also, I spotted two issues with this code.  You are not initiating the `array` called `$dayName` and nothing is being returned so the function will not send back output.  It should be like this.

```
    function monthLanguage()
{ 
    $dayName = array();
    if ($this->lang=='italian')//this statement is requared many times within the file!
    {
        $dayName[]="Dom";
        $dayName[]="Lun";
        $dayName[]="Mar";
        $dayName[]="Mer";
        $dayName[]="Gio";
        $dayName[]="Ven";
        $dayName[]="Sab";
    }else
    {       
        $dayName[]="Sun";
        $dayName[]="Mon";
        $dayName[]="Tue";
        $dayName[]="Wed";
        $dayName[]="Thu";
        $dayName[]="Fri";
        $dayName[]="Sat";       
    }
    return $dayName;
}
```

Also, the `$this` is not clear since that is usually used in the scope of a class, so perhaps you need to set the function like this:

```
    function monthLanguage($lang)
{ 
    $dayName = array();
    if ($lang=='italian')//this statement is requared many times within the file!
    {
        $dayName[]="Dom";
        $dayName[]="Lun";
        $dayName[]="Mar";
        $dayName[]="Mer";
        $dayName[]="Gio";
        $dayName[]="Ven";
        $dayName[]="Sab";
    }else
    {       
        $dayName[]="Sun";
        $dayName[]="Mon";
        $dayName[]="Tue";
        $dayName[]="Wed";
        $dayName[]="Thu";
        $dayName[]="Fri";
        $dayName[]="Sat";       
    }
    return $dayName;
}
```

And you would then call the function in PHP like this:

```
monthLanguage($this->lang);
```

Or like this:

```
monthLanguage($lang);
```

But it is unclear where this function is being placed or used, so clarify that to decide which is the best way to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use $this->lang - it's usually reserved for a method if I'm not mistaken.

Try replacing the function with this, should work like a charm.

```
function monthLanguage($lang) { 
    if ($lang=='italian')//this statement is requared many times within the file!
    {
        $dayName[]="Dom";
        $dayName[]="Lun";
        $dayName[]="Mar";
        $dayName[]="Mer";
        $dayName[]="Gio";
        $dayName[]="Ven";
        $dayName[]="Sab";
    }else
    {       
        $dayName[]="Sun";
        $dayName[]="Mon";
        $dayName[]="Tue";
        $dayName[]="Wed";
        $dayName[]="Thu";
        $dayName[]="Fri";
        $dayName[]="Sat";       
    }
}
```

Comment: *$this->lang - it's usually reserved for a method if I'm not mistaken.* - You are mistaken.